# Angular Primeng Calendar size scale

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I would like to modify the size of the Calendar popup date-time-picker (not the input field)
what kind of syntax should I use in SCSS??

[image]

I have try:

```css
p-calendar {
   font-size: 0.8rem;
}
p-calendar .date-picker {
   height : 200px;
}
```

update for my html:

```
<div class="date-time-picker" >
  <p-calendar
    class="calendar-control"
    [(ngModel)]="date"
    [showTime]="true"
  ></p-calendar>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML?

Comment: You should use the inspector in the browser to see which element you want to edit. Remember that editing some components from material is not easy, so you may use ng-deep and host on your css

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the scale of the calendar, you can follow these steps:

1. For all calendars in your component, add the following CSS code to your component's style file:

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-datepicker {
  transform: scale(0.7); /* Adjust the scale to your desired value */
}
```

This code uses the `:host` and `::ng-deep` selectors to target the calendar component and applies a scale transformation to adjust its size. You can modify the `0.7` value to increase or decrease the scale as per your requirement.

2. For a specific calendar in your component, you can add a `styleClass` property to the `p-calendar` component:

```html
<p-calendar styleClass="scale-calendar" inputId="basic" [(ngModel)]="date1"></p-calendar>
```

In the above code, we added the `styleClass` property with the value `"scale-calendar"` to the specific `p-calendar` component.

3. In the SCSS file of your component, add the following CSS code to target the calendar with the specified `styleClass`:

```css
.scale-calendar .p-datepicker {
  transform: scale(0.7); /* Adjust the scale to your desired value */
}
```

This CSS code targets the calendar component with the `scale-calendar` class and applies the scale transformation to adjust its size. Again, you can modify the `0.7` value to change the scale according to your needs.

By following these steps, you can change the scale of all calendars in your component or apply the scale to specific calendars using the `styleClass` property.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: I'm so sorry if my answer look like generated by an AI, but honestly 
I take a lot of time to answer the question, I know that using AI is illegal and I know that's plagiarism, I always try the solution using `Stackbiltz` and then answer the question but sometimes I use paraphrasing Tools  just to restructure the sentences in order to make the answer readable and understandable, I think that is acceptable, isn't it ? @tchrist